# How does the weakness of SHA-1 introduce attack vectors in SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, sha, openssh

The security branch of my company worries that the use of older versions of OpenSSH (pre-7.4), where the only Key Exchange Algorithm available is SHA-1 is a major security issue. They suggest generating new public/private keypairs for all users in the infrastructure.

As a Linux admin I'm supposed to be making a plan for fixing this issue, but when I try to research it, it seems that there is some mixup between the algorithm used to generate private/public keypairs, and the algorithms used in the connection handshake between two hosts.

As far as I can tell, the SHA-1 hashing algorithm is only used in the key exchange between two hosts, to validate each other, and has nothing to do with generating the public/private keypairs.

It also seems that the demonstrated vulnerability applies to things such as pdf documents, where there are tons of metadata that can be tweaked to try to generate an identical hash without actually generating visible text. I'm not even sure this is possible to implement in the SSH handshake.

My big question is: **If our servers are vulnerable because they use SHA-1 in the handshake, what are the worst case scenarios?**

- Can the attacker spoof a known host and capture sensitive information by having an unknowing user log into it?
- Can the attacker get a hold of login info directly or indirectly?
- Something else?

Please also correct me if I have misunderstood something, I have found a lot of conflicting information about this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SSH uses a hash algorithm in couple of places:

1. As a pseudo-random function in the key exchange (e.g., with `diffie-hellman-group14-sha1`).
2. As a message authentication code (e.g., `hmac-sha1`)
3. To sign a signature over the negotiated session hash to authenticate both parties (e.g., with `ssh-rsa`)
4. To sign certificates if you're using OpenSSH certificates (e.g., with `ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com`)

Uses 1 and 2 are still secure, since they rely on properties of the hash function that don't involve collision resistance, which is what's weak about SHA-1 (although there are uses of HMAC-SHA-1, such as commitment schemes, where collision resistance is required).  Therefore, there's no reason that SHA-1 itself is weak here.

Use 3 is more questionable, since you're performing a signature, where collision resistance is required, although this is probably not practically attackable.  The attacker would have to have some way of guessing the shared Diffie-Hellman secret or a derived value, and we generally expect that to be computationally infeasible.  That's because SHA-1 is weak to collision attacks, so an attacker has to be able to produce two messages (which, with current attacks, are of a certain form) that hash to the same value, and it would be hard to do that in an online manner without the assistance of the server.

Use 4 is a serious problem.  Because we assume users can generate their own key pairs, using SHA-1 to sign a certificate is very weak.  OpenSSH certificates contain somewhat less data than X.509 certificates and exploiting this is therefore likely to be more difficult, but this is the threat I would worry about most, and it's the one that the OpenSSH developers are most worried about as well.  If an attacker carried out an attack here, the attacker could get access to systems they should not due to an invalid certificate being accepted when it should not be.

So if you're not using OpenSSH certificates, you're probably not at a direct risk from attack.  However, there are more reasons to avoid using SHA-1 if you can:

1. It's weak in many practical cases and we prefer to use cryptographic primitives which are unambiguously strong.
2. We don't want to encourage others to use SHA-1 at all, since even if we're using it in a secure way, others might decide to use it as well and then use it in an insecure way.
3. It sets off security scanners and causes compliance problems, as you've noticed.

It goes without saying that all of these also apply to MD5, which you should definitely not use.  And there are some additional reasons why SHA-1-based algorithms are bad in SSH particularly:

1. Most of the SHA-1-based key exchange algorithms use groups that provide less than 128 bits of security.  Because the security of the key exchange is required for forward secrecy of the connection, you'd want to avoid using a weak group here.  The generic group exchange `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1` *could* be secure, but that depends on both the server and the client being configured correctly.
2. Using SHA-1 in the key exchange loses entropy (as outlined in RFC 4253) if you negotiate an encryption or MAC key longer than 160 bits.  Therefore, the most security you can possibly get out of using SHA-1 in the key exchange is 160 bits.
3. DSA (`ssh-dss`), which uses SHA-1 for signatures, is limited to 1024 bits in SSH, which is far too small for practical security.  RSA keys less than 3072 bits also offer less than 128-bit security.

128-bit security is the minimum level of security for practical matters these days.  Some organizations have requirements for 192-bit security.

If you can use any of the Ed25519, Curve25519, ECDSA, or ECDH algorithms that OpenSSH supports, these will use stronger hash functions and will avoid your entire problem.  They may also be available on older systems.  When in doubt, follow the [Mozilla recommendations](https://infosec.mozilla.org/guidelines/openssh.html).

Comment: It isn't clear if SSH the protocol limits DSS=DSA to 1024. rfc4253 references 186-2 which as of 2006 (with change notice 1) specified 1024/160 and SHA-1, and 4253 explicitly confirms SHA-1 but not 1024 or 160. OpenSSH the implementation will _generate_ (in ssh-keygen) only 1024/160, but will _use_ (in sshd and ssh) a DSA key generated e.g. in OpenSSL with larger p and even q, but with SHA-1 as explicitly required in 4253 thus losing the benefit. The 4253 scheme ssh-rsa also does any RSA size even 3072 with SHA-1, but rfc8332 schemes rsa-sha2-(256,512) fix this.

Comment: True, it's theoretically possible to generate larger DSA keys, but I'm not aware of any implementations which do that and not sure if they're interoperable across implementations.  I'm aware of RSA SHA-2, which is a good choice if you need RSA, but that doesn't help the OP who needs older system support.  Ed25519 is a better choice when possible because it's much easier to make constant time.

Comment: I don't quite understand why Use 3 is considered unfeasable; is it because the attacker would need to guess the output of the pseodu-random function from Use 1, in a short timespan?

Comment: Correct, and because the key exchange is single use.  A collision attack requires finding two messages that hash to the same value, so an attacker would have to create an exchange hash that is of a certain form and then cause a subsequent key exchange to use a similar exchange hash, which would require guessing the result of that key exchange in advance.

Comment: I see! And this weakness does not leave private/public keypairs vulnerable as SHA-1 is only used to verify the public key being sent. So for this to be feasable, they need to be the man-in-the-middle and also be able to guess the pseudo-random hash that the SSH-client "chooses", did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Correct.  Being able to create a hash collision doesn't leak the private key if that hash is used, at least not for the algorithms we use for SSH.  The attacker would only be able to guess the hash if the server colluded with it or re-used the ephemeral DH or ECDH key pair.  While the latter doesn't necessarily break the security of TLS, it's much riskier in SSH, and I'm not aware of any implementations which do that.

Answer (score 3):

Note that I'm not an expert in cryptography, so maybe ask this question too at [crypto.se](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). From my understanding there are 3 places where SHA-1 was used and where it gets disabled now:

1. Use as hash algorithm when generating the keys during the key exchange
2. Use as signature algorithm to verify the public key of the peer
3. Use as signature algorithm within a certificate hierarchy (PKI), so that one only need to trust an issuing CA and not each key

During the key exchange (#1) public/private keys are not involved so any weaknesses of SHA-1 in this place does not compromise the key pairs. It most it could compromise the single connection but even this is IMHO currently practically impossible since SHA-1 is just used as a hash and not for signing, i.e. collision and pre-image attacks are irrelevant here.

During authentication (#2) SHA-1 gets used as signature. A weak signature hash does not compromise the key pairs but at most would allow authentication of somebody not having the correct key pair. Even this is IMHO currently practically impossible, since without having access to the real key pair it is impossible to predict and fake the expected signature.

Use of SHA-1 as signature within a PKI (#3) is different though. A weak signature algorithm would allow the creation of a certificate which seems to be signed by the trusted CA and is thus accepted for authentication. The attacker has also sufficient time to create such a faked certificate.

In summary: No key pairs are compromised.
But if there was a PKI involved which used SHA-1 for signing, then a) SSH clients and servers should be hardened to no longer accept SHA-1 as certificate signature and b) all certificates signed with SHA-1 need to be replaced because they will no longer be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

(This came up because I was reminded that OpenSSH 8.8 disables the `ssh-rsa`(-SHA1) signature algorithm by default: https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.8.)

Summary:

- You don't need to regenerate RSA keys for this vulnerability.
- If possible, you *do* want to disable support for SHA-1 RSA host signatures with `HostKeyAlgorithms -ssh-rsa` on both clients and servers, if this is not already the default for your version of OpenSSH. (You can test this with `ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=-ssh-rsa`.)

  - You can also disable SHA-1 user signatures with `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes -ssh-rsa` (on both the client and server). There's no reason not to if you already disable RSA SHA-1 host signatures, unless e.g. servers have Ed25519 keys but some users still have RSA keys and are using a version too old for SHA-2 RSA signatures. OTOH, attacking this hash is much less practical since the AIUI this signature is sent over the encrypted connection, so it would require a malicious/compromised server or a weak cipher, and it doesn't look like any of the inputs to the user signature are directly attacker-controllable (see [RFC 4252 p. 10](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4252#page-10); the only thing not chosen by the client seems to be "the session identifier... is the exchange hash H from the first key exchange" which looks difficult to use to mount a collision attack).
  - If you don't have an alternative way of accessing the servers, disable these on the client and check that you can still authenticate to the server.
  - On the client, you can re-enable these on a per-host basis as necessary. If you do so, you might want to restrict the connection to a single known-good cipher and key exchange algorithm to mitigate against downgrade attacks (i.e. pick the strongest ones supported by both client and server, and avoid `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1` and `diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256` since those might allow an attacker to force the client into a weak/bogus group).
  - On the server, you can also enable `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes` on a per-user basis. (You can't enable `HostKeyAlgorithms` because the key exchange/host auth happens before the username is presented to the server.)

---

The relevant 2020 paper is [SHA-1 is a Shambles: First Chosen-Prefix Collision on SHA-1 and Application to the PGP Web of Trust](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/014.pdf) [Website](https://sha-mbles.github.io/) by Gaëtan Leurent Thomas Peyrin. See section 7.4.

Its relevance to SSH builds on the 2016 paper [Transcript Collision Attacks: Breaking Authentication in TLS, IKE, and SSH](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01244855/document) by Karthikeyan Bhargavan and Gaëtan Leurent, a.k.a. the "SLOTH" attack ([website](https://www.mitls.org/pages/attacks/SLOTH)). See section VI.C (pages 13-14).

The OpenSSH deprecation notice is at https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2.

My understanding of the papers:

- The 2016 paper outlines a downgrade attack to a weak cipher suite (without the ability to control the key). This is a problem if the client is configured to allow a weak cipher (e.g. rc4/arcfour*, any of the *-cbc ciphers when not paired with an *-etm MAC), but these are now disabled by default.
- The 2016 paper also hypothesizes that a MitM could attack Diffie-Hellman Group Exchange to "send a bogus or weak group to the client, and use it to control more fields in the session hash and mount new transcript collision attacks". I'm not sure what's possible to do here, but AIUI forcing the client into a weak group can completely break the client end of the connection. As an example of the kind of attack that might be possible, the paper uses a bogus Diffie-Hellman group to attack TLS (page 7) and "small subgroup confinement attack" against IKEv2 (page 13).
- I'm not sure if the downgrade attack can also downgrade the key exchange. Downgrading to one of the smaller fixed groups could make the connection vulnerable to LOGJAM. (The [2015 LOGJAM paper](https://weakdh.org/imperfect-forward-secrecy-ccs15.pdf) speculates that precomputation of a few 1024-bit groups is plausible for a well-funded attacker. The 1024-bit `diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` is no longer enabled by default; I don't know how feasible attacking a 2048-bit group is.)
- The 2020 paper says:

  > As in the TLS case, usage of SHA-1 to sign the transcript has been shown to be potentially vulnerable to the SLOTH attack, but this is not practical given the timing constraints (usually just a few seconds, but can be configured to a longer period of time).

  I can't find the source of this timeout of "a few seconds". In OpenSSH's `ssh_config`, `ConnectTimeout` defaults to [unlimited](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/V_8_2_P1/readconf.c#L1927) (i.e. the only timeout is the TCP timeout), and I haven't found a corresponding setting in `sshd_config`. (I don't know if a server timeout would help anyway.

  I'm also not sure that the attack in the 2016 paper needs to be done "online". From the paper, the attacker attacks the session hash

  > *H* = hash(*V<sub>C</sub>*|*V<sub>S</sub>*|*I<sub>C</sub>*|*I<sub>S</sub>*|*pk<sub>S</sub>*|*g<sup>x</sup>*|*g<sup>y</sup>*|*g<sup>xy</sup>*)

  by modifying *I<sub>C</sub>* in one direction and *I<sub>S</sub>* in the other to force a collision before *pk<sub>S</sub>*|*g<sup>x</sup>*|*g<sup>y</sup>*|*g<sup>xy</sup>*. Critically, I don't think the version strings *V<sub>C</sub>*,*V<sub>S</sub>* and protocol parameters *I<sub>C</sub>*,*I<sub>S</sub>* change between connections, which would allow the collision to be precalculated for a bunch of common versions/configurations of OpenSSH (or the versions/configurations used by the attacker's target).

To answer some questions:

- There is definitely a "mixup between the algorithm used to generate private/public keypairs, and the algorithms used in the connection handshake between two hosts": The name `ssh-rsa` is used for both the RSA key itself and the RSA-with-SHA-1 signature algorithm. You can use a "ssh-rsa" key with the `rsa-sha2-512` and `rsa-sha2-256` signature algorithms (configured in `ssh_config` as `PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes`). See also `ssh -Q key` and `ssh -Q sig`.
- There is no need to regenerate keys for this vulnerability, though you might want to check that all RSA keys are at least 2048-bit (or switch to other public key algorithms).

  - (While there have been some issues that required regenerating keys, like [DSA-1571](https://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571) from 2008, this isn't one of them. Regenerating RSA keys will not help.)
- **Can the attacker spoof a known host and capture sensitive information by having an unknowing user log into it?**

  That depends on what the attack can accomplish. As an extreme example, forcing a downgrade to the "none" cipher leaks everything sent over the connection. Known-weak ciphers are no longer enabled by default, and the "none" cipher is no longer compiled in by default.

  Forcing the connection to use a weak group/subgroup can also leak everything (page 13 in the 2016 paper), as well as allow the attacker to impersonate the client (i.e. run arbitrary commands on the server). This is the attack I'd worry most about, but unfortunately the papers do not explore in depth.
- **Can the attacker get a hold of login info directly or indirectly?**

  AIUI usernames/passwords are protected with the same cipher as everything else in the connection. Usernames and passwords also tend to be *more* susceptible to attacks on weak ciphers since they tend to be transmitted at predictable byte positions.
- **Something else?**

  Attacks only get better.

  It is very easy to make statements like "X is hard" or "X is impractical" only to be proven wrong due to insufficient creativity on the writer's part. "Transcript collision attacks" were the novel subject of the 2016 paper, despite being a potential attack on SSH/TLS for well over a decade. People were initially not worried about attacks on CBC in TLS since they required many connection attempts to be successful, until the authors of the BEAST attack paper noticed that this is easy to do with JavaScript in a second tab.

  It's easy to dismiss weak ciphers being enabled because the client/server should negotiate a stronger one, and it's also easy to dismiss downgrade attacks because weak ciphers should be disabled. Both of these reasons are true! But for defense-in-depth, it's best to make sure *both* are configured securely by default, perhaps with exceptions as necessary.

  > "older versions of OpenSSH (pre-7.4)"

  [OpenSSH 5.7](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.7) supports ECDSA, [OpenSSH 6.5](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.5) supports Ed25519, and [OpenSSH 7.2](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2) supports RSA with SHA-256/SHA-512 signatures. (They might not be compiled in by your distribution, though.) But if your hosts cannot upgrade to a newer version of OpenSSH, I'd worry about other security vulnerabilities more than a cryptographic attack on SSH (unless SSH is the only attack surface).